# How to return React-Native Component in Vue-Native method

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue.js, vue-native

I write application with Vue-Native and in my case i use React-Native component, that uses prop function `renderItem` returning React-Native element (for ex. `<View>`)

I have Vue element `wineCard`, which i should return in this function

In React this function looks something like this:

```
  renderItem = ({ item, index, move, moveEnd, isActive }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onLongPress={move}
        onPressOut={moveEnd}
      >
      <wineCard wineItem={item} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
```

How it can be done using Vue-Native?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a React-Native component in Vue-Native by making a `.js` file with the React-native component in it and put it in your Components directory in your Vue-Native application.

for example:

Components/flex.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Views/Home.Vue:

```
<template>
  <view>
    <Flex/>>
  </view>
</template>
 <script>
  import Flex from '.././Components/flex.js'

  export default {
    components:{Flex}
  }
</script>
```